# Weird strips with quads in OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, antialiasing, distortion

Everything is on the screenshot I just took... Basically, It does that even when there's no lighting enabled... Is it antialias related?

Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1G5E.png

@Axel, Here my code for a single cube :

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glColor3f(r,g,b);

glNormal3f(0, 0, -1);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y + radius, position.z - radius);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y - radius, position.z - radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y - radius, position.z - radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y + radius, position.z - radius);

glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y + radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y - radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y - radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y + radius, position.z + radius);

glNormal3f(-1, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y + radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y - radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y - radius, position.z - radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y + radius, position.z - radius);

glNormal3f(1, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y + radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y - radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y - radius, position.z - radius);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y + radius, position.z - radius);

glNormal3f(0, -1, 0);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y - radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y - radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y - radius, position.z - radius);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y - radius, position.z - radius);

glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y + radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y + radius, position.z + radius);
glVertex3f(position.x - radius, position.y + radius, position.z - radius);
glVertex3f(position.x + radius, position.y + radius, position.z - radius);

glEnd();
```

Comment: I think the problem is in your code...

Comment: It might be antialiasing related. What's the code you're using to enable it?

Comment: non-existent haha but without antialias is it supposed to be as intense as this ?